# Fourier transform of the laplacian operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to find the Fourier transform of the Laplacian operator for a function $u(x)$ where $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.I am trying to use the definitions but I am struggling cause we work in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Include in the question the definitions you are using, what is your work so far, and where are you stuck.

Comment: Yes, this is standard stuff, so I imagine that the real task is for you to make more precise in your own mind what the issue is. Then you will be able to ask an answerable question.